# handling non existent entries during transpose

Tags: awk, git-bash

I have a data file and need to do transpose in awk handling non-existent values also.

```
id|type|cost|date|ship
0|A|223|201603|PORT
0|A|22|201602|PORT
0|A|422|201601|DOCK
1|B|3213|201602|DOCK
1|B|3213|201601|PORT
2|C|2321|201601|DOCK
```

I need to transform and get the output as

```
id|type|201601|201602|201603|
0|A|422.0|22.0|223.0|
1|B|3213.0|3213.0|n/a|
2|C|2321.0|n/a|n/a|
```

Im trying pivot in awk, but it is not working.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" ' NR>1 { k=$1 OFS $2;id[k]++;date[$4]++;cost[k]=$3 } END {printf("%s","id|type|");for(i in date) printf("%s|",i);print ""; for(i in id) { printf("%s|",i); for(j in date)  { if( (i) in cost) { printf("%s|", cost[i OFS j]);} else { printf("%s|","n/a")} } print "" } }  ' data.txt
```

It is just printing.

```
id|type|201601|201602|201603|
0|A||||
1|B||||
2|C||||
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"; PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} NR>1{hdr[$4]; map[$1 OFS $2][$4] = $3} END {printf "%s", "id" OFS "type" OFS; for (i in hdr) printf "%s", i OFS; print ""; for (r in map) {printf "%s", r OFS; for (i in hdr) printf "%s%s", (map[r][i] == "" ? "n/a" : sprintf ("%.1f", map[r][i])), OFS; print ""}}' file

id|type|201601|201602|201603|
0|A|422.0|22.0|223.0|
1|B|3213.0|3213.0|n/a|
2|C|2321.0|n/a|n/a|
```

A more readable `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="|"
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
}
NR > 1 {
   hdr[$4]
   map[$1 OFS $2][$4] = $3
}
END {
   # print header
   printf "%s", "id" OFS "type" OFS
   for (i in hdr)
      printf "%s", i OFS
   print ""
   # print body
   for (r in map) {
      printf "%s", r OFS
      for (i in hdr)
         printf "%s%s", (map[r][i] == "" ? "n/a" : sprintf ("%.1f", map[r][i])), OFS
      print ""
   }
}' file
```